# test if my string contains a specific file name

Tags: iphone, nsstring

How can i test whether my NSString contains the following file name : test.pdf

This is my code

```
    NSString *pdfLocation = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is your friend. You could have found e.g. [this](http://objcolumnist.com/2009/04/12/does-a-nsstring-contain-a-substring/).

Answer (score 0):

[rangeOfString:options:range:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)